# Cropping UIImage Screenshot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimage

I am currently replacing UIGetScreenImage() in my code as it results in the C99 error.

I am replacing it with [this code from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html), which the `screenshot` method returns a `UIImage`.

My attempts at cropping and saving the image are as follows :

```
UIImage *returnedImage = [self screenshot];
// Get image to save
CGImageRef screen = returnedImage.CGImage;
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];

// Image cropping
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([img CGImage], CGRectMake(0, 5, 768, 1004));
UIImage *img2Save = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

// Request to save the image to camera roll
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img2Save, self, nil, nil);
```

I have also tried cropping it in the `screenshot` method before I return it, but to no avail.

With both attempts the uncropped `UIImage` that is returned from the `screenshot` method is saved.

Is there something obvious I'm leaving out? I have looked at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655176/problem-in-cropping-the-uiimage-using-cgcontext) but can't see the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   //create a context to do our clipping in
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
   CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   //create a rect with the size we want to crop the image to
   //the X and Y here are zero so we start at the beginning of our
   //newly created context
   CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
   CGContextClipToRect( currentContext, clippedRect);

   //create a rect equivalent to the full size of the image
   //offset the rect by the X and Y we want to start the crop
   //from in order to cut off anything before them
   CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * -1,
                                rect.origin.y * -1,
                                imageToCrop.size.width,
                                imageToCrop.size.height);

   //draw the image to our clipped context using our offset rect
   CGContextDrawImage(currentContext, drawRect, imageToCrop.CGImage);

   //pull the image from our cropped context
   UIImage *cropped = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   //pop the context to get back to the default
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   //Note: this is autoreleased
   return cropped;
}
```

Then call the code with something like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   //draw the whole lights off image
   //the on images will be drawn overtop
   [lightsOffImage drawInRect:rect];

   //if we don't have any lights on... no point in continuing
   if( numberOfLightsOn < 1 )
     return;

   //figure out the dimensions of numberOfLights on bulbs
   CGSize croppedSize = CGSizeMake(LIGHT_WIDTH * numberOfLightsOn, LIGHT_HEIGHT);
   CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, croppedSize.width, croppedSize.height);

   //get the "on" bulbs by cropping the image
   UIImage *cropped = [self imageByCropping:lightsOnImage toRect:clippedRect];

   //create a rect to draw the newly cropped on images to
   CGRect lightsOnRect = CGRectMake(LIGHT_BULB_OFFSET_X,
                                    LIGHT_BULB_OFFSET_Y,
                                    croppedSize.width,
                                    croppedSize.height);

   //draw the "on" lights
   [cropped drawInRect:lightsOnRect];

   //cropped is autoreleased so no need to worry about cleanup
}
```

May this code helping to you.

Comment: Hi @neon samuel, I had tried to call that function from the other so thread. What happens is that it seems to Invert the picture and shrink the image. Is this due to the coordinates I am passing to it? I didn't think it would inver as the first 2 arguments I pass to the method are 0.