# CGImage memory size returning weird results

Tags: memory, memory-management, uiimage, cgimage, cgimageref

I'll make it quick and straightforward.

I'm using this method to calculate 'UIImage' memory size.

```
extension UIImage {

   func memorySize() -> size_t {
        let image = self.cgImage!
        let size =  image.height * image.bytesPerRow
        return size
    }
}
```

I'm cropping an `UIImage`. **Before** cropping our image ( Meaning using the original image).
 This is the image stats : `Width` -> 2668 | `Height` -> 2000 | `scale` -> 1 | `memorySize` -> 21,376,000.

**After** cropping the **original image** using

```
 func passCroppedImage(_ myFrame : CGRect) -> UIImage {
        let imageRef:CGImage = preview.image!.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!
        let croppedImage:UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
        return croppedImage
}
```

My **cropped image** stats are : `Width` -> 1126 | `Height` -> 2000 | `scale` -> 1 | `memorySize` -> 21,376,000.

**How is it possible, that the cropped image width/height size is different, but the memory size remains the same?**

I've made a small research, according to apple docs, about  `image.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect) -> CGImage`

```
   The resulting image retains a reference to the original image,
   which means you may release the original image after calling this function.
```

But again, if i'm trying to release the CGImage, it says `Swift` handing the memory management. I'm confused. **ANY help would be much appreciated!**

Comment: Yeah, this is known behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2655176/1271826. If you end up creating a new JPEG or PNG from this image, it will be smaller than the JPEG/PNG from the larger image. Or if you draw this to a new context with its own `CGDataProvider`, then the bytes per row will be reset. But the simple cropping does not. It's favoring performance over memory usage.

Comment: Re "trying to release the `CGImage`", yep, Swift does that memory management for us. So don't worry about that. That documentation reference was for us poor suckers writing Core Graphics code in Objective-C, where we had to do our own releasing of foundation objects we were working with.

Comment: Hey Rob! Thank you for commenting. Unfortunately i'm not using the UIImage for JPEG/PNG, i will use it for CIContext to apply filter ( In other words, it will remain at the app memory). That's why i've wanted to make sure the memory size is reduced. Correct me if i'm wrong, but memory size does affect CIFilter filtering time, or not?

Comment: @Rob Forgot to tag you. sorry.

Comment: "Unfortunately i'm not using the UIImage for JPEG/PNG, i will use it for CIContext to apply filter" ... yeah, so see my second point about drawing it to a new context. That answer I linked you to has a second, highly voted answer that shows how to do that.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I'll check it out. Your patience is priceless Rob. Always a pleasure sir!